# Why is my script not writing anything to a csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, svg, export-to-csv

I am working on creating a python file to translate a path found within an svg file, translating it into a csv file, however I am restricted from using any libraries other than csv. I have gotten this far and it will not export any data into the csv file. I am wondering where I have gone wrong.

```
import csv

def parse_coordinates(svg_path):
    commands = set(['M', 'm', 'L', 'l', 'H', 'h', 'V', 'v'])
    current_x, current_y = None, None
    coordinates = []

    parts = svg_path.split()
    for part in parts:
        print("PartL", part)
        print(part)
        if part[0] in commands:
            command = part
        else:
            coords = list(map(float, part.split(',')))
            if command == 'M' or command == 'm':
                current_x, current_y = coords[0], coords[1]
                coordinates.append([current_x, current_y])
            elif command == 'L' or command == 'l':
                current_x, current_y = coords[0], coords[1]
                coordinates.append([current_x, current_y])
            elif command == 'H' or command == 'h':
                current_x = coords[0]
                coordinates.append([current_x, current_y])
            elif command == 'V' or command == 'v':
                current_y = coords[0]
                coordinates.append([current_x, current_y])
    return coordinates

# Read SVG file
with open('Path5.svg', 'r') as f:
    svg_content = f.read()

# Find the path element by parsing the content directly
start_idx = svg_content.find(' d="') + 3
end_idx = svg_content.find('"', start_idx)
path_data = svg_content[start_idx:end_idx]

# Parse coordinates from the path data
coordinates = parse_coordinates(path_data)

# Write coordinates to CSV file
with open("coordinates.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(coordinates)

print("Coordinates written to coordinates.csv")
```

Here is the svg I am working off of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
   width="759.3833mm"
   height="460.74869mm"
   viewBox="0 0 759.3833 460.74869"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1" />
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-57.875793,-38.539758)">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583"
       d="M 58.008075,50.130434 63.021117,499.1559 817.12609,497.7236 816.40994,364.51987 H 150.3913 V 152.53975 H 805.6677 V 38.67205 H 148.24285"
       id="path1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I have tried printing out the coordinates to see what I am receiving and that is returning blank. I have tried a different style of data gathering such as:

```
import csv

def parse_coordinates(svg_path):
    coordinates = []

    # Split the path data by spaces
    parts = svg_path.split()

    # Initialize variables to track the current command and coordinates
    current_x, current_y = None, None

    # Iterate over the parts
    for part in parts:
        # Check if the part starts with a letter (indicating a command)
        if part[0].isalpha():
            # Update the current command
            command = part
        else:
            # If the part is not a command, it must be coordinates
            # Split the part by commas to extract x and y coordinates
            x_y = part.split(',')
            if len(x_y) == 2:
                x, y = map(float, x_y)
                current_x, current_y = x, y
                coordinates.append((x, y))
            elif command == "H":
                x = float(x_y[0])
                current_x = x
                coordinates.append((x, current_y))
            elif command == "V":
                y = float(x_y[0])
                current_y = y
                coordinates.append((current_x, y))

    return coordinates

# Read SVG file
with open('Path1.svg', 'r') as f:
    svg_content = f.read()

# Find the path element by searching for '<path d="' and '"/>'
start_idx = svg_content.find('<path d="') + len('<path d="')
end_idx = svg_content.find('"', start_idx)
path_data = svg_content[start_idx:end_idx]

# Parse coordinates from the path data
coordinates = parse_coordinates(path_data)

# Write coordinates to CSV file
with open("coordinates.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for coordinate in coordinates:
        writer.writerow(coordinate)

print("Coordinates written to coordinates.csv")
```

However I am getting the same issue of no coordinates.

Comment: You're not taking into account the space in `svg_content.find(' d="')`. So it should be `start_idx = svg_content.find(' d="') + 4`